# Verce: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer, vercel

Why is it that when I run it locally it works, but when I deploy it to Vercel it gets an error
eror msg :

```
Cannot find module '../sdam/server_selection'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js
- /var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js
- /var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js
- /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
- /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/task/___now_launcher.js
- /var/runtime/index.mjs
Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 506.41 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

I have installed the required dependencies
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV5UM.png)

this is my index.js code :

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const projectRoutes = require("./routes/ProjectRoute");
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL).then(()=>{
    console.log("Database connected");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
})



const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(projectRoutes)
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

app.listen(PORT, () => 
console.log(`server is running in port ${PORT}`)
);
```

can anyone help, I'm a beginner

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.